# CSS not loading properly only in my Firefox

Tags: jquery, html, css, facebook, codeigniter

## CSS is not loading for my site Locopari.com correctly in my Browser.

> Check in your browser  http://locopari.com/

If I reduce it just by 1 pixel it will display correctly, I tried all other browser works correctly , any browser setting required ?
You can check it on your browser, if found any problem , please report me. 
Thank You.

> Here is code for CSS

```
.dealItem
{
display:inline-block;
padding: 25px 20px;
width: 224px;
}
```

> Link of screenshot is http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/109/screenshot1vo.png/

Comment: Refer if by either class(.) or Id (#) hope u missing that in ur css

Comment: Please update your FF. It is showing fine in my FF.

Comment: hi bro can you provide a screen shot... it work right in my browser...

Comment: I have linked my screenshot here please check it & give feedback accordingly

Comment: I'm using FF 18.0.2, it's most updated version with zoom set to normal

Answer (score 1):

Error

```
.dealItem
{
   display:inline-block;
   padding: 25px 20px;
   width: 224px;
}
```

**OR**

```
#dealItem
{
   display:inline-block;
   padding: 25px 20px;
   width: 224px;
}
```

you forget to define if its class or id.

Change it accordingly.